# Can I change an Esper bolt statement on the fly?

Tags: apache-storm, esper, topology

I'm using storm to process some data streams.

At the beginning I read an xml file where I find statements used in Esper bolts. Soon after I define my topology and run it on a cluster.
Now, if I want to change a statement in a bolt, I have to modify the xml, stop the cluster, and restart it from the beginning.

Is possible a scenery that sees a thread that checks my xml and when finds new statements defined can update the Esper Bolt with the new statement while the cluster is going on?

I defined an Esper bolt as follows:

```
    String statement = "select count(*) as userPerMinutes from event.win:time_batch(60 sec)";
    EsperBolt esperBolt = new EsperBolt.Builder()
        .inputs().aliasComponent("user")
        .withField("field1").ofType(String.class)
        .withField("field2").ofType(Integer.class)
        .withField("field3").ofType(Long.class)
        .toEventType("event")
        .outputs().onDefaultStream().emit("userPerMinutes")
        .statements().add(statement)
        .build();
```

In a thread how can I access to this bolt and edit/add/remove its statement?
Through the topology? And how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a similar system. Using storm + esper to run a distributed event process system. Esper can remove and add epl at runtime. How my system does so is, start a new thread in bolt to sync epl from a database from time to time. Update the changed one (remove and then add).

Hope this helps.

---

add code might be useful

```
EPStatement statement = esperAdmin.getStatement(rule.getName());
if (statement != null) {
    statement.destroy();
}
```

Comment: How can I update the statement of an esper Bolt? In the externa thread, if I get from DB a new statement for that bolt what do I do? Do I cleanup the bolt and rebuild it? Or what?

Answer (score 1):

I'm familiar with Esper and don't see any issue with adding or removing statements on the fly. And I don't think Storm would keep you from doing that.

Comment: How? How can I get my bolt and edit/add/remove its statement? Have I to build() it finally as in its definition?